# How to display array data from MySql in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

So I a Manifest where you can add multiple customers, produce etc and it saves in the DB as an array

[image]

Now I'm making a page where you can view all the manifest info I want it to look something like this

[image]

if I try to do something like this `{{ $manifest->customer_name }}` i get a error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` because it's an array I'm only having trouble with displaying the array data

Controller Code to get the correct manifest

```
public function view($id) {

    $manifests = Manifest::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('users.manifest.view', compact('manifests'));
}
```

view - usually I would just put `{{ $manifets->customer_name }}` but i can't because it an array

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="15%">Customer</th>
                                <th width="15%">Produce</th>
                                <th width="15%">Task</th>
                                <th width="15%">Units</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $manifests->customer_name }}" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

print_r

```
 App\Manifest Object
(
    [table:protected] => manifest
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_id
            [1] => date
            [2] => driver_name
            [3] => truck_number
            [4] => run_number
            [5] => customer_name
            [6] => produce
            [7] => task
            [8] => units
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => array
            [produce] => array
            [task] => array
            [units] => array
        )

    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [user_id] => 1
            [date] => 2017-11-02
            [driver_name] => Harry Oberlander
            [truck_number] => 7989
            [run_number] => 8
            [customer_name] => ["evergreen","Surplus"]
            [produce] => ["Apples","Meat"]
            [task] => ["Pick Up","Delivery"]
            [units] => ["3 skids","1"]
            [created_at] => 2017-11-02 04:49:49
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-02 04:49:49
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [user_id] => 1
            [date] => 2017-11-02
            [driver_name] => Harry Oberlander
            [truck_number] => 7989
            [run_number] => 8
            [customer_name] => ["evergreen","Surplus"]
            [produce] => ["Apples","Meat"]
            [task] => ["Pick Up","Delivery"]
            [units] => ["3 skids","1"]
            [created_at] => 2017-11-02 04:49:49
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-02 04:49:49
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [events:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

)
```

here is the updated code

```
    @foreach($manifests as $manifest)
        <tr>
           <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $manifest['customer_name'] }}" />
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $manifest['produce'] }}" />
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $manifest['task'] }}" />
           </td>
        </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: you a loop with your array so that you can present your data that way

Comment: @hungrykoala do mind posting an example?

Comment: I can't without knowing your code for the display

Comment: @hungrykoala let me know if that's the code your looking for

Comment: can you do a `print_r($manifests);` and show to the result here

Comment: @hungrykoala I could only style the code inline Idk how to style it as a block

Comment: do it like this: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($manifests);` so that the formatiing will be better

Comment: @hungrykoala done

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@foreach($manifets as $manifestos)
   @for ($counter = 0; $counter < sizeof($manifestos['customer_name']); $counter++)
<tr>
   <td>

   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameoffield" value="{{ $manifestos['customer_name'][$counter] }}" />
   </td>
   <td>

   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameoffield" value="{{ $manifestos['otherfields'][$counter]}}" />
   </td>
   //more td here depending on the fields you want to display
</tr>
   @endfor
@endforeach
```

Comment: i tired that but i get Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you show it in your post and what line the error is pointing at

Comment: oh sorry it's an array. let me update my code. Also you have an extra <tr> in your code

Comment: Nope the foreach outputs 4 tr's when it should only output 2 and the input values are blank

Comment: Can you post your updated code so that we can have a look at it?

Comment: You need to do additional foreach inside your foreach since your data is also array

Comment: I'm pretty sure i know what you mean but can you please update your example just ti make sure

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing array (which is an object in PHP) in database.
This makes a form unrecognisable when you retrieve back the data.

You should serialise the array before storing it to database. It will save the data as a kind of JSON string.

```
serialize($array_var_name);
```

Further to get the array back you can use

unserialize($data_var);

Now you can use the array as usual array